# Value Websocket not found scala application

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket

I'm trying to work with websocket on scala and i just dont get why i have this error :

```
[error] /Users/tom/dev/gokera/app/controllers/FriendsController.scala:52: not found: value Websocket
[error]   def websocket = Websocket.using[String] {
[error]                   ^
[error] one error found
```

Actually my code looks like that :

```
import akka.actor._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.iteratee._
import play.api.mvc._

def websocket = Websocket.using[String] {
    val out = Enumerator.imperative[String]()
    val in = Iteratee.foreach[String] {
      msg =>
        out.push(msg)
    }
    (in, out)
  }
```

I think i didn't forget any import but the error seems to say the opposite.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typo error
use capital S at **WebSocket.using[String] {**

```
def websocket = WebSocket.using[String] {
    val out = Enumerator.imperative[String]()
    val in = Iteratee.foreach[String] {
      msg =>
        out.push(msg)
    }
    (in, out)
  }
```